# How to get the time of Computer and not server Java vaadin

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, vaadin, vaadin6

Hey how to get the time of the computer and not the server using vaadin because getDate return to me the time of the server but i want the client computer time  ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vaadin has a class called WebBrowser that provides useful information about the client (browser):

You can access the current WebBrowser instance for example as follows:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        setMainWindow(new Window());

        ApplicationContext context = this.getContext();
        if (context instanceof WebApplicationContext) {
            WebBrowser webBrowser = ((WebApplicationContext) this.getContext()).getBrowser();

            Date now = webBrowser.getCurrentDate(); // Returns the current date and time on the browser
        }
    }
}
```

For more information about the WebBrowser class, see its [JavaDocs](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/terminal/gwt/server/WebBrowser.html).

Comment: Hey thnaks for the answer and information about the WebBrowser Class , But did'nt work it gives always the server Date , after seeing the Documentation i found that the method :  public Date getCurrentDate()

    Returns the current date and time of the browser. This will not be entirely accurate due to varying network latencies, but should provide a close-enough value for most cases. Also note that the returned Date object uses servers default time zone, not the clients.

Comment: The WebBrowser class has other time and timezone related methods too, I think you should be able to calculate time in browser by using those methods.

Answer (score 0):

Vaadin runs on server side, so everything you do there corresponds to the server itself. For your problem you can probably create a vaadin widget to get clients time(-zone) and pass it to the server.

Comment: as you can see in Henri Kerola's answer, vaadin already provides a feature to get the date from the client. I didn't know that.