# Get user’s current default time zone within a Vaadin 8 app

Tags: browser, timezone, vaadin, default, vaadin8

Is there a way to determine the user’s web browser’s current default time zone from within a Vaadin 8.1 app?

Preferably get a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) object rather than the legacy class [`TimeZone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html).

The [`WebBrowser`](https://vaadin.com/api/8.1.2/com/vaadin/server/WebBrowser.html) class offers getter methods for `getCurrentDate()`, `getDSTSavings()`, `getRawTimezoneOffset()`, `getTimezoneOffset()`, and `isDSTInEffect()`. But none of those are a `ZoneId`. A mere offset is not a time zone. A time zone is a history of [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) for a particular region, covering past, present, and future changes such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

I am aware that ultimately the only reliable way to know the user’s desired/expected time zone is to explicitly ask them in my app. But it would be nice to have a guess as a default.

---

The [proposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10313668/642706) is not a duplicate, asking about getting the *current date-time* whereas my Question is about the *time zone*. Furthermore, my Question asks about the modern java.time classes while the proposed Question is about the flawed legacy date-time classes.

Comment: @cfrick Nope, not a duplicate. I'm asking about *time zone*, not the *current time*. See my edits.

Comment: WebBrowser also holds the offsets.  Currently there is no more (JS/Browser has no more to offer)

Comment: @cfrick If you are confident of no other options, please make that an Answer for me to accept and close the Question. And kindly retract the incorrect duplicate proposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative for querying [`WebBrowser`](https://vaadin.com/api/8.1.3/com/vaadin/server/WebBrowser.html) (or any other Vaadin API) is to use the client [IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) and use a online service to get the geo information, including ZoneId.

See related Questions:

- [Find time zone from IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2898581/642706)
- [How to determine a zip code and city from an IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/348614/642706)
- [Mapping US zip code to time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2456324/642706)
- [Determine a User's Timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13/642706)
- [Geocode an IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3232516/642706)

Comment: Hmm, if you use the geo information *only* for this purpose, you are probably right, "a workaround". However, in many scenario's you will use the geo data in a broader context and then this approach might be better imho (separation of concerns)

Comment: I suggest adding that to your Answer.